# CMake - Eclipse CDT 4 Project set Flag Syntax

Tags: cmake

I am trying to set a value in my CMakelists.txt but I have trawled the manual and google but can't get it right for this one.

I have tried

```
SET (CMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT ON)
```

and

```
SET (CMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT BOOL:ON)
```

but nothing sems to work.  Here is an exerpt from my CMakeLists.txt

```
#
#Eclipse Standards
#
SET (CMAKE_ECLIPSE_EXECUTABLE "/Applications/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse")    
SET (CMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT ON)
```

Comment: Regarding this flag in particular, it does not seem to have any effect in particular any more... I checked the generated project files and they are identical, and it looks to me that now (I have cmake 2.8.11) the source project generation is activated by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt should work fine.  If you want to specify the variable's type too, you'd need the `CACHE` version of [`SET`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aset), which would look like

```
SET (CMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT ON CACHE BOOL "Documentation of var")
```

However, the problem is more likely to be that the variable is being set correctly, but is having no effect.

This could be because your version of CMake is less than 2.8.7 (when this variable was first implemented, replacing the deprecated `ECLIPSE_CDT4_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT`).

Another reason could be that the variable is designed to be set via the command line, i.e.

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT=ON
```

This will have a similar effect to setting the variable using the `CACHE` option above, but it will be set before any of the script in the CMakeLists.txt has run, especially before the `PROJECT` command, where much of the work in setting up the correct CMake variables is done.

Comment: From what I have seen, at least with CMake 2.8.11 that variable has no impact whatsoever (anymore) on the Eclipse project file generated...

Comment: @Antonio, I have CMake 2.8.11.2-1ubuntu5 and `CMAKE_ECLIPSE_GENERATE_SOURCE_PROJECT` is honoured. It has no effect if you build from the source directory, obviously.